# Distrowatch mistake?

Tags: distributions

Why does Distrowatch state that [Red Hat is Fedora based](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=redhat) and [Fedora is independent](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=fedora) when Fedora's [history page](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/History) indicates that's not the case? Am I misunderstanding, or is Distrowatch wrong?

Comment: Your question assumes you know the answer and everybody else is wrong. First try to figure out what people mean by terms like "independent" and "based on", then the usage on distrowatch might make more sense. There is always the possibility of a mistake being made, but first understand the terminology yourself.

Comment: What exactly do you don't understand? Red Hat is based on Fedora and Fedora isn't based on any other distribution.

Comment: @LEt_Me_Be: did you read what had I posted?: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/History

Comment: @Caleb: I'm asking that that why is there such a big typo in Distrowatch. Why is there when it's not true?

Comment: @LanceBaynes How does that relate? Fedora was previously called Red Hat Linux, now it's called Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux is based on Fedora.

Comment: @LanceBaynes: It's not a typo, it's actually legitimate. Yes I read what you posted and yes I know the history. Having a history of connections is not what distrowatch means by being based on! See my answer.

Comment: The word "based" in this regard references its current design. It is not in reference to its history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These statements are not contradictory, both of them are true. You are either mixing up the names of distros or the definition of the terms involved.

You are probably mixing up RH with RHEL. The old days of *RedHat* and the current lineup of *Fedora* and *Redhat Enterprise Linux* are very different.

*RedHat Enterprise Linux* is basically a professionally rehashed version of Fedora with a support contract. *CentOS* is basically a *RHEL* copy-cat without the support contract offering.

*Fedora* is independent of any other current distribution. In fact it is one of the leading independent distros. Independent means that it's development is a free-standing operation. Dependent or in Distrowatch's language "based  on" distros are ones that are only modifications of other distros and are reliant on the other distros work to continue to move forward.

An example of a dependent distro would be *CentOS*, which relies on repackaging stuff from *RHEL*. *RHEL* in turn relies on the development work done on *Fedora* in order to continue. *Mint* relies on *Ubuntu*'s development process and just layers on their own changes.